# Unable to use OpenLayers library in Browser Debugger Console (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, openlayers-3, console.log

I am having one application which has OpenLayers Map and implemented using reactjs with OpenLayers library. I am trying to get the latitude and longitude of the map from the browser console in order to use the same in my selenium automation.

I am using the below code in the console and getting an error as below

**Error:**

```
"Uncaught TypeError: map.getLayers is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:5"
```

**Script:**

```
   map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer){
    if(layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector){
      var features = layer.getSource().getFeatures();
      features.forEach(function(feature) {
        console.log("Features Coordinates from Main Class :"+ol.proj.toLonLat(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()));
     });
    }
  });
```

When I inspect OpenLayersMap and it has class name as map.So, I have used `map.getLayers()` in script.

Comment: Are you importing that class?  Is it defined for sure?

Comment: I haven't imported in console. Could you please share the steps to do the import in browser?

Comment: In your code in React add a line with `global.map = map;` or maybe `window.map = map;` (don't remember exactly...) just after you create your `var map = new ol.Map(` block in your current code. Then, what you want should be testable in the browser. In fact, your issue is not related to OpenLayers but to JavaScript and the relationship between your project bundler and global/local scope

Comment: Thanks Thomas!!! After adding the global.map = map;, then above mentioned error is solved. but now getting an error for the ol. as "ol is not defined".  Whether I need to inject the OpenLayer library in browser?

Comment: Do the same with `global.ol = ol;` PS: normally, it's not recommended to "leak"a global (bypassing best practices is fine as long as you know "why" IMHO)